# Angular 2. Emitting hover event in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, events, angular

I have template for some (MyCmp) component(`<my-cmp></my-cmp>`) like this

```
<template ngFor let-r [ngForOf]="range" let-index="index">
  <span>{{ index < 5 ? 'Y' : 'N' }}, {{r.data}}</span>
  <i (mouseenter)="somefunc()" (click)="elefunc()"></i>
  ....
</template>
```

I configure TestBed for MyCmp component via special TestComponent

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [TestComponent], imports: [MyModule]}
TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, {set: {template: '<my-cmp></my-cmp>'}});
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
context = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
element = fixture.nativeElement;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

I think it's not important. Tests worked.

```
element.querySelectorAll('i')[0].click(); //fine
```

But i don't know how i should emit hover(*mouseenter*) and *mouseleave* event

```
element.querySelectorAll('i')[0].hover() // not a function
element.querySelectorAll('i')[0].mouseover() // not a function
element.querySelectorAll('i')[0].createMouseEvent('mouseover') // not a function
```

Comment: In below cases you are emiting these events similar to click.

Comment: Yes. I tried emit mouseenter event similar to click, but it does not works

Comment: element.querySelectorAll('i')[0].onmouseover()

Comment: *TypeError: element.querySelectorAll(...)[0].onmouseover is not a function* 
I think onmouseover it's function for listening, not for emitting

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/LdBshha7Raym80q9ce1L?p=preview

Comment: *is not a function*
 Maybe it is Angular-specific or testing-specific issue. Thanks for help

Comment: I can't believe this doesn't have more views and answers. I am facing this exact problem with lack of docs on google.

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 12):

In case you haven't had an answer for this, you can use the dispatchEvent of the nativeElement  in the following way:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}));
```